# El programa en java no imprime el resultado

Tags: java, imprimir

Trato de hacer un programa que convierta un numero decimal al sistema binario, octal y hexadecimal hice un menu y todo, la conversion a binario funciona pero al ingresar el numero en las otras conversiones, simplemente no imprime nada.
 aqui el programa.

El objeto

```
package com.modelo;
public class Numero {
private String num;

public Numero() {
    num = null;
}
public Numero (String num) {
    this.num = num;
}

public String getNum () {
    return num;
}
public void setNum (String num) {
    this.num = num;
}

}
```

Las interfaces

```
package com.control;
import com.modelo.Numero;

public interface conversiones {
public int decimal(Numero n); 
public int octal(Numero n);
public int hexa(Numero n);

}
```

La clase que se supone debe imprimir el resultado

```
package com.tester;
import com.control.Metodos;
import com.control.control; 
import com.modelo.Numero;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tester {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
    control ctr=new control();
    Numero n=new Numero();
    int op;
    do {
        System.out.println("¿Que conversion desea realizar?:\n 1- Decimal a Binario \n 2- decimal a octal \n 3- decimal a Hexadecimal");
        op = entrada.nextInt();
        switch (op) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println ("Ingrese el numero: ");
            n.setNum(entrada.nextInt());
            System.out.println (ctr.decimal(n));
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println ("Ingrese el numero: ");
            n.setNum(entrada.nextInt());
            System.out.println (ctr.octal(n));
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println ("Ingrese el numero: ");
            n.setNum(entrada.nextInt());
            System.out.println (ctr.hexa(n));
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Finalizado");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Opcion Ivalida");
            break;  
        }
        } while (op != 4);
    }
}
```

La clase que hace las operaciones

```
package com.control;

import com.modelo.Numero;

public class control implements conversiones {

public String imprime(Numero n) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    sb.append("Numero: ").append(n.getNum());
    sb.append("Binario: ").append(decimal(n));
    sb.append("Octal: ").append(octal(n));
    sb.append("Hexadecimal: ").append(hexa(n));
    return sb.toString();
}

@Override
public String decimal(Numero n) {
    String bin = new String("");
    while (n.getNum() > 0 ) {
        bin = n.getNum() % 2 + bin;
        n.setNum(n.getNum() / 2);

                }
    return bin;
} 

@Override
public String octal(Numero n) {

    String oct = new String("");
    while (n.getNum() >= 0) {
        oct = n.getNum() % 8 + oct;
        n.setNum(n.getNum() / 8);
    }
    return oct;
}

@Override
public String hexa(Numero n) {

    String hex = new String("");
    int resi = 0;
    while (n.getNum() >= 0) {
        resi = n.getNum() % 16;
        if (resi >= 0 && resi <= 9) {
            hex = resi + hex;
        } else {
            switch (resi) {
            case 10:
                hex = "A" + hex;
                break;
            case 11:
                hex = "B" + hex;
                break;
            case 12:
                hex = "C" + hex;
                break;
            case 13:
                hex = "D" + hex;
                break;
            case 14:
                hex = "E" + hex;
                break;
            case 15:
                hex = "F" + hex;
                break;
            }
            n.setNum(n.getNum() / 16);
        }
    }
    return hex;
}
}
```

[image: Lo que me da de resultado]

Comment: Hey Star, Puedes agregar la clase conversiones  y Numero ?

Comment: agregue el resto del codigo

Comment: A mí si me arrojó un resultado, lo ejecuté en **eclipse**:¿Que conversion desea realizar?:
 1- Decimal a Binario 
 2- decimal a octal 
 3- decimal a Hexadecimal
**1**
Ingrese el numero: 
**10**
**1010**
¿Que conversion desea realizar?:
 1- Decimal a Binario 
 2- decimal a octal 
 3- decimal a Hexadecimal

Comment: como dije, solo hace la conversion de decimal a binario, pero no funciona con las otras opciones

Comment: Dentro de tu interface conversiones tienes valores de retorno como int y dentro de la clase control son String los métodos, en realidad te funciona el código ? @StarHikari

Comment: si perdon, mande las interfaces equivocadas, es que es un programa que funciona a la inversa

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lo que pasa que en tus ciclos tienes un mayor o igual a 0, entonces llega un momento en el que todos los resultados dan cero pero el ciclo sigue corriendo, puesto que sigue aceptando la condición y por ende se cicla.

Debes de cambiar la tu while de esta manera:

```
public String octal(Numero n) {

String oct = new String("");

while (n.getNum() > 0) {
    oct = n.getNum() % 8 + oct;
    n.setNum(n.getNum() / 8);
}
return oct;
}
```

De igual forma para el Hexadecimal.

Pruebalo.

Comment: eso resolvio el del octal el del hexadecimal sigue igual

Comment: En realidad el OP tiene más problemas en su código, el código que agrego a su pregunta no funciona adecuadamente. Esto solo resuelve un problema.